# JSF2 LogicalViews - Losing the Current Page From the Map

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

We recently updated our Application to use JSF 2.1.3

We have an existing page that has three framesets (left nav, main, footer).  Clicking on something in the main frame, causes the footer frame to be reloaded with new content.  Because of this, we are losing the main frame from the logical view map after (eg. if com.sun.faces.numberOfLogicalViews is set to 10, we lose the main frame after 9 clicks).  After which, trying to submit the main frame causes it to re-render, skipping the action method it's bound too.

Is there any way to keep that logical view from being removed from the map without increasing the number of logical views?  I'm not sure why, but this behavior didn't occur when out app was using JSF 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

We solved this problem by overriding the `StateManagerImpl`, and storing this particular view client side, instead of server side.

It appears in previous versions of jsf, you only needed to override the `isClientSide` method, but you now need to override the methods to write and restore state.